# How to get cookie of nopcommerce customer using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, nopcommerce

I want to know how to get nopcommerce customer cookie using javascript?

I have tried to many things to get cookies but did not succeed.

As per I have searched Nopcommerce saves the cookies in http only secure format so client side script did not read cookies values.

please help how to get it?